# GeoCouch support in Node.js

Tags: node.js, couchdb, couchdb-nano, cradle

I would like to use `[GeoCouch](https://github.com/couchbase/geocouch/)` and `CouchDB` with `Node.js` and just wondering whether

- [Nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano)
- [Cradle](https://github.com/flatiron/cradle)

are supporting `GeoCouch` views?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like nano [supports extensions](https://github.com/dscape/nano#extending-nano), I could not find an equivalent in cradle's documentation.

In particular, [this](https://github.com/dscape/nano/blob/master/lib/nano.js#L84-L101) is the internal function that is being used. It looks like you can just pass in parameters like `path` to set a custom URL. (I don't know much about GeoCouch, so I can't give specifics)

If you do end up writing up a good collection of helper functions that other nano users could benefit from, consider publishing it on npm. (maybe named `nano-geocouch`?)